# GCSE level trigonometry question

Tags: trigonometry

In the UK we do GCSE exams and this is one of the GCSE questions I can't solve at this time of night lol. First part is easy but I can't see a way around part B. Any help would be much appreciated.

http://s17.postimg.org/8me1qdbkf/Screen_Shot_2015_09_21_at_21_28_51.png

http://postimg.org/image/9oo88wudn/

Comment: Hint: sine rule.

Comment: knew i should've read that page...

Comment: To whom it may concern: GCSE = General Certificate of Secondary Education. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: An inferior way to solve this problem is to express $x$ numerically in degrees and go on from there.  As my answer shows, that is unnecessary.  That necessarily involves rounding, and rounding should be saved for the last step (except when one _knows_ what will be the effect of earlier rounding on the bottom line, and even then there may be uses for a bottom line in closed form). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the image links are broken; consequently, it is unclear what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

$\angle DBC = 45^\circ$ and $\angle BCD = \arctan \dfrac{18} 6 $.  Therefore $\angle BDC = 180^\circ - 45^\circ - \arctan\dfrac{18} 6$.

So then you have the three angles of $\triangle BDC$ and you have the length of one of the sides, so you can use the law of sines.

$$\sin x = \sin \angle BCD = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac{18}{\sqrt{18^2+6^2}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{3^2 + 1^2}}. $$

$$\sin \angle DBC = \frac{\sqrt 2} 2$$

\begin{align}
\sin \angle BDC & = \sin\left( 180^\circ - 45^\circ - \arcsin\frac 3 {\sqrt{10}} \right) \\[10pt]
& = \sin\left( 45^\circ + \arcsin\frac 3 {\sqrt{10}} \right) \\[10pt]
& = \sin 45^\circ \cos\arcsin\frac 3 {\sqrt{10}} + \cos 45^\circ \sin\arcsin\frac 3 {\sqrt{10}} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\sqrt 2}2 \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{10}} + \frac{\sqrt 2} 2\cdot\frac 3 {\sqrt{10}} = \frac 1 {2\sqrt 5} + \frac 3 {2\sqrt 5} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 2 {\sqrt 5}.
\end{align}

The law of sines then tells us that
$$
\frac{6\text{ cm}}{2/\sqrt 5} = \frac{BD}{3/\sqrt{10}}.
$$
Dividing both sides by $\sqrt 5$, we get
$$
\frac{6\text{ cm}} 2 = \frac{BD\cdot\sqrt 2} 3.
$$